# Override subject of Fiddler Certificate

Tags: https, fiddler

Is there a way to change the subject of the certificate Fiddler uses when re-encrypting https traffic? Currently, it says CN=DO_NOT_TRUST_FiddlerRoot. I have a program that reads the subject and I'd like to run some tests where I customize the CN, O, and OU of the subject.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiddler can be reconfigured to use a custom certificate generator:

> Fiddler uses a pluggable architecture for certificate generation.
>   Developers provide their own certificate-related logic by implementing
>   the ICertificateProvider3 interface on an assembly specified by the
>   fiddler.certmaker.assembly preference, which defaults to
>   "certmaker.dll". [[source](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/faq---certificates-in-fiddler)]

Therefore with some .Net development you could develop an Fiddler add-on that implements the [ICertificateProvider3](https://www.fiddlerbook.com/om/html/AC773C7A.htm) and generates certificates exactly the way you need it. If the number of domains is limited you could even use pre-generated certificates which would simplify the "generator" logic.